# What privileges should I set for the MYSQL DB in CPanel for Wordpress Installs

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, security, privileges

By default all the options are ticked but I read somewhere a way back that some privileges should be unticked to increase security.

Can anybody advise on the best settings for the privileges on a MYSQL DB in Cpanel for Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually depending on your needs
If you are asking about the most secure one 
It is to disable read/write/execute from all types of users

Note :
this [article](http://www.woothemes.com/2013/09/improve-your-wordpress-security-with-these-10-tips/) might help